# jQuery: problems with hide() and show()

Tags: jquery, function

I've worked on a function using jQuery which hides and shows an image, letting some content in a `<div>` to be shown. The thing is that even though I succesfully hide the image and then change the class associated to the button in order to be able to call the `show()` function, the image won't re-appear. This is the code I've written so far (which does not work):

```
$('.viewVideo').click(function(){
    var wood = $(this).attr('id');
    var current = '.' + wood + 'Image';
    console.log(current);
    $(current).hide();
    $('.viewVideo').removeClass('viewVideo').addClass('viewPhoto');
});

$('.viewPhoto').click(function(){
    var wood = $(this).attr('id');
    var current = '.' + wood + 'Image';
    $(current).show();
    console.log(current);
    $(current).show();
    $('.viewPhoto').removeClass('viewPhoto').addClass('viewVideo');
});
```

Comment: Changing the class of an element doesn't change what events are bound directly to it.

Comment: on a side not, watch when using `console.log` as it will break your javascript code in some browsers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `on()` event rather than try to bind a `click()` event to your `.viewPhoto` class.

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object.

Change your code to;

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewPhoto', function(){
    var wood = $(this).attr('id');
    var current = '.' + wood + 'Image';
    $(current).show();
    console.log(current);
    $(current).show();
    $('.viewPhoto').removeClass('viewPhoto').addClass('viewVideo');
});
```

This is because when you are trying to bind the click event to `.viewPhoto` it doesn't exists as it is dynamically added/created. However, you can bind it to your document, **or even better the first non-dynamic element in the DOM hierarchy**.

So it would be `$([your-first-non-dynamic-element]).on(....)`

I would spend some time reading more about the `on()` event here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: or possibly reading more about event handling in general in this case.

Comment: +1 I beat you to it, but your answer seems alot more useful than mine!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `on` trigger with elements that change dynamically (which in this case is your class).

```
$('.parent_element').on('change','.viewPhoto', function(){
    // do something
});
```

Read more about this here: http://api.jquery.com/on/
It saved me alot of headache!